# Using jQuery .html with carriage returns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an MVC project. I have a container div that I want to add a partial view to. I get an error because my partial view's html has carriage returns.

JavaScript:

```
$("#containerOptions").html('@{Html.RenderPartial("_DropDownOptions", Model);}');
```

Partial View:

```
<div id="divOptions">
   <label>I would like to browse by:</label>
   @using (var dd = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new DropDown("Select Option").Class("dropDownElement").Id("dropDownOption")))
   {
      @dd.Header("Otpions");
      @dd.ActionLink("City", "#").Class("dropDownElement");
      @dd.ActionLink("Zip", "#").Class("dropDownElement");
      @dd.ActionLink("County", "#").Class("dropDownElement");
   }                                                                                                                                                             
</div>
```

I know my html code is not the issue because it works elsewhere. I have also duplicated the issue by just putting `<p>Hi</p><p>Fred</p>` in my partial view, which works.

But

```
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Fred</p>
```

does not work.

Is there a way to force the call to .html to ignore the carriage returns in my document? I would prefer not to remove them as it greatly decreases readability.

Edit:

I attempted to do a string replace to remove the new lines, but it did not work.

```
var s = '@{Html.RenderPartial("_DropDownOptions", Model);}'

var bob = s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');

$("#containerOptions").html(bob);
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't accept multilines string. You need to escape your new lines or remove it.

Comment: Well.... That's kind of what my question was asking how to do... I tried doing a replace for the new line character, but either did it wrong, or just doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Maybe you should show us your regexp? I can help if your regexp is wrong, but ASP.net / razor is not my expertise. Not much of a help i am.

Comment: Edit to show the replace i tried.

Comment: Don't inject HTML into string constants. That has many problems (as you are finding). Try the solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of injecting a HTML string constant into Javascript code, inject your view HTML into a hidden element on the page, as HTML, and reference that:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
     @Html.Partial("_DropDownOptions", Model)
</script>
```

`text/template` is an unknown content type, so is simply ignored for rendering.

### jQuery:

```
// This reparents the elements
$("#containerOptions").append( $('#template').children() );
```

### or

```
// Slightly slower, but leaves the original intact
$("#containerOptions").html( $('#template').html() );
```

This give you much better readability and flexibility. HTML in strings is generally a "bad" idea.

Comment: Wow very neat solution. Does exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I use the same technique for HTML templates as much easier to read than HTML in strings.

Comment: OId answer, but helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @Nsevens: It's not the age of the answer... it's what's in it that counts :) Some techniques live on for years. Just used this one again myself last week. Thanks

Comment: @GoneCoding ain't that the truth! ;)